# Celestron NexStar 130 SLT Computerized Telescope GoTo Not Accurate

Tags: star, planet, telescope, amateur-observing

I am trying to use a Celestron NexStar 130 SLT Computerized Telescope, but I am not able to use the GoTo function.

1. I do the three start alignment, it confirms matches,
2. I make sure the level is exactly level before and after,
3. I finally punch in a planet to slew to

...and once the telescope has slewed to the planet I see nothing in the eyepiece except pin point dots spread out.

Also, the words on the hand control are very hard to read because the letters are overlapping each other while the words are panning off the screen. I already tried factory resting which didn't work. The words are in English.

What would my next step be?

[image: Example of Celestron NexStar 130 SLT Computerized Telescope]

Example image, [Source](https://www.telescopesplus.com/products/celestron-nexstar-130-slt-computerized-telescope)

Comment: It sounds like there are two separate problems. You can't see the object clearly (a visual or optical problem) and the alphanumeric display on the control is unclear (electronic or software problem). What does "once it's there" mean? Can you tell if it's pointed close to where the planet is? What about choosing a different object that you can be sure, like the Moon? That would let you know if the pointing is at least roughly correct. Also, can you mention if you can ever see anything clearly through the telescope? Even daytime objects on the horizon? (don't look anywhere near the Sun!

Comment: I've adjusted the formatting of your question and added an image of a NexStar 130 SLT. From this I can see two things; 1) there is some kind of finder device shown behind the eyepiece, I'm not sure if has optics or it's just see-through, can you at least see the planet through that finder device? 2) the display is LCD, probably a dot matrix. Is it at least displaying the right language? Are you observing from an unusually cold or hot location - does it work differently indoors?

Comment: Have you input the date in the right format?  It may want mm/dd/yy (ie the American way round) or vice versa.

Comment: Make sure you use the lowest-power eyepiece (largest focal length, no Barlow) to get the largest field of view when you initially goto an object.

Comment: I found out something strange. When the telescope arrived the collimator screws for the primary mirror in the rear were completely loosened. So, now i had to collimate the telescope. I bought the highest rated laser collimator on amazon. But here's the strange part, I can adjust the collimator screws until the laser dot goes perfectly in the center while using the laser collimator but if i take the laser collimator off and put it back on 180 degrees turned from what it just was its way off now. Maybe this has to do with a lot of my problems not seeing detail. More info when skies clear later.

Comment: @KingGeorgeGopro  Are you tightening the locking screws well after you collimate? Just don't give up until you figure this out. It's worth it.

Comment: @Alphecca Of course i did